# How to convert from curl to python

Tags: python-3.x, splunk-sdk

How to convert this to python requests?

```
curl --noproxy '*' -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     -k --user "admin:password"  \
     -d"search=| savedsearch mysearch" \
     -X POST 'https://splunk:8089/services/search/jobs' 

def no_ssl_verification(session=requests.Session):
    old_request = session.request
    session.request = partialmethod(old_request, verify=False)

    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InsecureRequestWarning)
        yield

    session.request = old_request


url='https://splunk:8089/services/search/jobs'
jsonDict = {"search": "search=| savedsearch mysearch"}
print(jsonDict)
proxy = {'http': None, 'https': None}
with no_ssl_verification():
    r = requests.post(url, data=jsonDict, headers={'username':'admin', 
       'password':'password'}, json=jsonDict, verify=False, proxies=proxy)
    print (r.text)
```

=========

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <messages>
    <msg type="ERROR">Unauthorized</msg>
  </messages>
</response>
```